# Unicode character escape sequence are not printing correctly in handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

I am getting issues with Unicode character escape sequence. In my application my team using the Unicode character escape sequence for the localization.
The Unicode character escape sequence like below

```
\u1ee3
\u1ed7
\u0110
\u0103 and so on..
```

while using this characters i am getting incorrect characters like

> ?

What should i do for this. Is this problem with handlebar templating.

How can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about handlebars templates themselves, they are HTML script tag contents. HTML unicode sequences look like this: `&#x1ee3;` and not like `\u1ee3`.

If you're talking about rendering JavaScript variables, it should work; are you sure your page is displayed as Unicode?